# Can't assign value to a reactiveVal because It is NULL

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

I plan to make an app where I preprocess data, depending on what preprocessing method user wants to apply to the recipe.
Each preprocessing method is on a different observeEvent() that takes action when their own button is pressed.
That's why i want a reactiveVal where the recipe is stored so I can apply only the ones I want (different imputations, near zero variance, scale, etc)

Because of that, have a reactiveVal initialized:

```
object_recipe <- reactiveVal()
```

And the next block of code:

```
 observeEvent(input$recipe{
    req(train_data())
    
    object_recipe() <- recipe(formula = Survived ~ ., data = train_data())
  })




observeEvent(input$imputation_btn,{
    req(input$imputation_method, input$imputation_vars, object_recipe())
    
      if(input$imputation_method == "knn")  
        object_recipe() <- step_impute_knn(
          recipe = object_recipe(),
          predictor = all_of(input$imputation_vars),
          neighbors = input$knn_value,
        )
      
      if(input$imputation_method == "bagged_trees")  
        object_recipe() <- step_impute_bag(
          recipe = object_recipe(),
          predictor = all_of(input$imputation_vars)
          )
      
      if(input$imputation_method == "mean")  
        object_recipe() <- step_impute_mean(
          recipe = object_recipe(),
          predictor = all_of(input$imputation_vars)
        )
      
      if(input$imputation_method == "mode")  
        object_recipe() <- step_impute_mode(
          recipe = object_recipe(),
          predictor = all_of(input$imputation_vars)
        )   })
```

When It runs, an error occurs:

> Error in <-: lado izquierdo de la asignación inválida (NULL) ( invalid
> (NULL) left side of assignment)

If I try to use a local variable to the second observeEvent It works, but then I cannot use that recipe In another observeEvent that wants to do another preprocess method on top of It.

Comment: You can’t assign to a reactive value via `<-`. And in fact an expression of the form `foo() <- value` is **always** invalid in R, there is *no way* to make it work. In general, `foo(…) <- value` calls a *replacement function* (such as `names()<-`). However, a replacement function call *must* have at least one argument. It cannot have zero arguments.

Comment: Place `test <- reactiveVal(initialValue)` inside your server function, but outside any reactive scope.  Then reference or modify `test` inside a reactive scope.  See, for example, [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.1.0/reactiveval).

Answer (score 0):

`reactiveVal` do not function the same way as `reactiveValues`.

```
# declare
test <- reactiveVal(initialValue)

# getValue
value <- test()

# setValue
test(value)
```

If you don't want to get lost with different semantics, you can use a single value `reactiveValues` that will behave more or less the same way as `input` and `ouput`.

```
# declare
test <- reactiveValues(value=initialValue)

# get value
value <- test$value

# set value
test$value <- value
```

Comment: My problem Is still the same, If I create a reactiveVal, assigning the recipe value outside a reactive context It gives me an error (because u cannot use recipe(...) outside of It apparently), but If I do It inside a reactive context I cannot use It in another reactive one because "object_recipe function cannot be found" on the consecutive ones.

Comment: It's hard to further answer your question. Imagine we must complete your code with missing parts (data, ui,) to test and diagnose where the problem is. Try to reformulate your question with a minimal reproducible code